# ESA's snap-python (snappy) isn't working with python 3.5 and later

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, version, snap-python

As in ESA's snappy official [installation guide](https://senbox.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SNAP/pages/50855941/Configure+Python+to+use+the+SNAP-Python+snappy+interface), supported python versions are only:  2.7, 3,3 and 3.4

I need to install ESA's snappy library for python 3.6. Is there any way i could do so?

Comment: Seems to be a long-term problem: https://senbox.atlassian.net/browse/SNAP-626

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I could use ESA's snappy with python 3.6 but I first had to install jpy from github.

```
git clone https://github.com/bcdev/jpy.git
cd jpy/
```

Activate virtual environment if someone uses one

```
source ~/venv/venvsname/bin/activate
```

Build the wheel

```
python3.6 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Copy the created .whl file into snappy directory

```
cp dist/*.whl "~/.snap/snap-python/snappy"
```

Run setup to add jpy to your packages

```
python setup.py install
```

Then, in order to load snappy library we could either append path

```
import sys
sys.path.append('~/.snap/snap-python/')
import snappy
```

Or copy snappy directory into environment site-packages directory

```
cp ~/.snap/snap-python/snappy ~/vens/venvsname/lib/python3.6/site-packages
import snappy
```